# vb.net bug when trying to showdialog

Tags: vb.net

when i try to show dialog of one of my forms it displays this error all other forms work perfectly i have tried to copy the code into another form happened the same 
here is the error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in hyper market system.exe
>
> Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See
>   Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

here is all my code

```
Public Class farm
    Dim inifile As New IniFile(myfiles & "\system.ini")
    Dim myfiles As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\HMsystem"

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    Dim total As Long = 0

    Dim productnum As String = TextBox1.Text

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim productnum As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim num As String = TextBox2.Text
        Dim itemname As String = inifile.GetString("productname", productnum, "غير موجود")
        Dim price As String = inifile.GetString("productprice", productnum, "غير موجود")
        ListView1.Items.Add(productnum)
        ListView1.Items(Count).SubItems.Add(itemname)
        ListView1.Items(Count).SubItems.Add(num)
        ListView1.Items(Count).SubItems.Add(price)
        total += price
        Count += 1
        Dim a As String = inifile.GetString("productquan", productnum, "0")
        Dim itemquannow As String = inifile.GetString("productquan", productnum, "0")
        If itemquannow <= 5 Then

        Else
            MsgBox("لم يبق الا 5 من هذا المنتج")
        End If
        inifile.WriteInteger("productquan", productnum, a - num)
        MsgBox("تم الاضافة")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label4.Text = total & "           السعر النهائي"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListView1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        Count = 0
        total = 0
        MsgBox("تم الشراء بنجاح")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Label4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label4.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Read the exception message and stack trace to find out what's wrong.

Comment: i will try deleting code in my form and see if it works thx :)

Comment: my best GUESS is that it's  not finding the file you're trying to pull from.  Try and put breakpoints in debugger and see how far you get.  That exception tells me that it's pulling a null value for something and trying to use it.

Comment: The message states the error is occurring when the form is created.  You need to check the .designer.vb, specifically any New() or custom routines and the InitializeComponent() routine.  As everyone else has said, read the message, trace the stack and then use breakpoints if you're still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an error message like that, i.e. "An error occurred creating the form", it almost always means the same basic issue: you have an event handler that is being raised because of a property value set in the designer and that event handler assumes that the user has made that change after the form has been displayed.  For instance, if you set the `Text` property of a `TextBox` in the designer then that's going to raise the `TextChanged` event.  If you have handled that event then your event handler is going to be executed during the initialisation of the form, before it has been displayed to the user.  If you assume that, for instance, an item is selected in a `ComboBox` then you're in trouble because there will be no such selection.

As the error message states, look at the `InnerException`, which will tell you exactly where the original exception was thrown.  That will tell you which event handler is the issue and you can then look at the code in that method and determine what would cause an issue if the form had not yet been displayed.  If in doubt, update your question with the code of that event handler and tell us where the exception was thrown, which the stack trace will tell you.

Comment: i deleted a long then redefine  it as an integer it worked :)